# How to convert xAct output to FeynCalc input?

Tags: xact, feyncalc

For the packages xAct and Feyncalc, is there a way to convert xAct output into Feyncalc input? I have an expression of one rank and four rank tensors as an output from xAct. The number of terms is huge that a clever way to import it would be greatly appreciated. Any suggestions?